# Contradiction between 2 elements in Judaism - Tchiat Hametim and Gilgul

Tags: olam-haba-world-to-come, resurrection-of-the-dead

In Judaism, there are 2 terms, that contradict.

1) Tchiat Hametim (reviving of the dead)

2) Gilgul/Leida Mechadash (Reborning)

- If you lived as a Person 1, and died, and later revived as Person 2. When Person 2 dies too, and Tchiat Hametim comes, will you be revived as person 1 or 2?

This really confuses me. When you answer, please try to write sources.